# How to permanently change the DOM on an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, dom, windows-8

I'm making a Windows 8 Store App using HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. The app allows its user to make lists, and manage the items inside of those lists. I've managed to edit lists and do everything I want, but the problem is that once you close the app, everything is reset, because none of the changes to the DOM I made (such as elements I added or removed) are saved, and I lose all of the lists and their items I made. Is it possible to edit the DOM in such a way that it edits the actual HTML file, so that everything I did is still there once I open the app again? If not, what are some alternate methods for saving user data once the app is closed? 
Thanks, 
Daniel

Comment: Have you looked into local storage? http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: I'll note that you should perceive the DOM as a 'view' (in the MVC context). Your scripts should be making persistence-worthy changes to a backing store (your MVC 'model') which is then serialized. You'll find your program will be more maintainable that way.

Answer (score 0):

This may be late but hope this helps.

You can use HTML local storage.With local storage, web applications can store data locally within the user's browser.

Before HTML5, application data had to be stored in cookies, included in every server request. Local storage is more secure, and large amounts of data can be stored locally, without affecting website performance.

Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never transferred to the server.

Local storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from one origin, can store and access the same data.

You can store data by

`localStorage.setItem("Name", "Daniel Bezden");`

And then you can access them by

`localStorage.getItem("Name");`

Good luck!