# persistent dynamically-created DOM in popup.html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

so i have stored attributes and innertext details using Chrome Storage API, then when popup.html is opened, DOM nodes will be created based on those details and appended to my popup's html, then in a callback, those DOM details will be erased from the Storage. But when I click the popup again, previously dynamically-created elements are not there anymore. Now, I'm wondering what are the ways to make those dynamically created elements to be persistent in my popup.html even after their details have been erased from Storage?

I can think of 2 ways:

1) Use Storage e.g. transfer those details to other keys before erasing.

2) [As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255348/how-to-permanently-change-the-dom-on-an-html-file#comment26770669_18255348), serialize persistent-worthy changes to a 'backing store'. But I have totally no clues where to begin with this approach..